# Copy Semantics and Comparison

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Is there a way to get a copy of all of the values in a YAML::Node object into a new object (i.e. a clone)? Also is there a way to test for equality between two YAML::Node objects by the values in the node (i.e. a .equals() function as opposed to an .is() function)?

Consider the following example:

```
YAML::Node a;
a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"][3] = 1;
std::cout << "A_____\n" << a << "\n\n\n\n";

std::cout << "Test 1\n";
YAML::Node z = a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"];
z[3] = 2;
std::cout << "Z_____\n" <<  z << "\n";
std::cout << "A_____\n" <<  a << "\n\n\n\n";

std::cout << "Test 2\n";
YAML::Node b = a;
b["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"][3] = 3;
std::cout << "B_____\n" <<  b << "\n";
std::cout << "Z_____\n" <<  z << "\n";
std::cout << "A_____\n" <<  a << "\n\n\n\n";

std::cout << "Test 3\n";
YAML::Node c;
c["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"][3] = 3;
std::cout << "C_____\n" <<  c << "\n";
std::cout << "A_____\n" <<  a << "\n";
std::cout << "a == c: " <<  bool(a==c) << "\n";
std::cout << "z == a[\"x\"][1][\"y\"][2][\"z\"]: "
            <<  bool(z == a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"]) << "\n\n";
```

which outputs the following when run:

```
A_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 1



Test 1
Z_____
3: 2
A_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 2



Test 2
B_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 3
Z_____
3: 3
A_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 3



Test 3
C_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 3
A_____
x:
  1:
    y:
      2:
        z:
          3: 3
a == c: 0
z == a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"]: 1
```

In test 1, modifying `z` also modifies the value of `a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"]`, and similarly in test 2, modifying `b` is equivalent to modifying `a`. Are these copy semantics considered part of the API (i.e. are they likely to change in the future)? I'd like to be able to write code such as `z = getZ()`, and have `getZ()` return `a["x"][1]["y"][2]["z"]` (the names for "x", "y", and "z" might change in the future). Modifying `z` would then modify `a` as shown in the example.

Also though, is there a way to get a clone of `a` into a new object `b` so that modifying `b` does not also modify `a`?

In test3, the values in `c` are the same as those in `a`. Is there some way to do `a.equals(c)` for YAML::Node objects in general to test if the values in the two nodes are all the same? In the example, `a.equals(c)` would be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deep-copy a node:

```
YAML::Node node = /* ... */;
YAML::Node other = Clone(node);
```

(This is now implemented; you can see the old [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=162).)

The current behavior is intended (in other words, the typical "copy" is just setting identity), and will not change.

As for equality, that's a very difficult problem, in general, for YAML. There's some discussion on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/issues/detail?id=60) on the yaml-cpp project page.